# Libgdx Actor.setBounds() as a hexagon (or other non-rectangular shape)

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to make a bunch of hexagonal tiles interactible. I believe the easiest way to do this is to create them as Actors and make the touchable, but I can't figure out how to set the bounds so that they are hexagon shapes rather than rectangular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `hit()` method to test the shape of a hexagon. Look at the Actor source code to see how it works for a rectangle.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. Follow up question, I'm using the following in my hit method to test if I can cut a corner off the hitbox:

`return x >= 0 && x < getWidth() && y >= 0 && y < getHeight() && y > ((-6/20)*x + 6) ? this : null;`

This part `y > ((-6/20)*x + 6)` seems to make it so it only registers clicks where `y > 6`. Any reason for this?

Comment: Integer math, 6/20 is equal to zero. Use 6f/20f.